# List node not being freed, still disappears

Tags: c, linked-list

And yet another unexpected behaviour of my version of ls.

Context: I generate an output list for each directories opened, then add a node to show which directory will be displayed next, as does the original ls.

To handle the `-a` option, I simply remove all nodes starting with `"."` when there is no -a option given to my ls. To avoid removing the node showing the directory pathname, I check that the node content doesn't start with `"./"`, nor `".:"`.

Here's the code :

```
t_list          *ft_rem_hidden(t_list **output)
{
    t_list          *cursor;
    t_list          *tmp;

    cursor = *output;
    while (cursor)
    {
            tmp = cursor->next;
            if (ft_strnequ((char const *)cursor->content, ".:", 2) == 0
                    && ft_strnequ((char const *)cursor->content, ".", 1)
                    && ft_strnequ((char const *)cursor->content, "./", 2) == 0)
                            ft_lstfreeone(output, cursor);
            cursor = tmp;
    }
    return (*output);
}
```

Now the funny part. I checked the (whole) list before the loop, and the first node's content is, as expected `".:"`
I checked that said node doesn't pass the if, and as expected, it doesn't.
I checked the list after the while loop, aaaaand the `".:"` isn't there anymore.

Here's the code for `ft_lstfreeone`, although I've been using it for a while without issue, I can't see any other culprit. Well, except my ignorance.

```
void        ft_lstfreeone(t_list **alst, t_list *to_free)
{
    t_list      *cursor;
    t_list      *tmp;

    if (alst && *alst && to_free)
    {
        cursor = *alst;
        if (cursor == to_free)
        {
            *alst = cursor->next;
            ft_memdel((void **)&cursor->content);
            ft_memdel((void **)cursor);
        }
        else
        {
            while (cursor && cursor->next && cursor->next != to_free)
                cursor = cursor->next;
            if (cursor->next == to_free)
            {
                tmp = cursor->next;
                cursor->next = cursor->next->next;
                ft_memdel((void **)&cursor->content);
                ft_memdel((void **)tmp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where is my node? That's pretty much all that's keeping me from having a functional ls, and it's rather infuriating. Any hints welcome.

Edit : Some more testing shows that it's only the .: node which is concerned. If I ask my ls to display the content of any other dir, its name shows just fine on the first line.

Edit 2: I created a git repo with the sources for the whole thing, in case someone wants to take a closer look at that. https://github.com/pdecrat/ft_ls

Comment: Looks like cursor will be pointing at freed memory after the call to ft_lstfreeone().  Who knows what mess that will cause.  You need to at save cursor->next or save cursor and advance it before the ft_lstfreeone() call.

Comment: @TonyLee I get what you're saying, but so far it seems to just replace the node it was pointing to to the next one. For exemple, to display the list content, I print its content then free it with     lstfreeone, all in a while loop, and it's working as I explained. Pure luck ?

Comment: you need to place & in front of any variable you pass to ft_memdel() so ft_memdel((void**) cursor) needs to be ft_memdel((void**) &cursor) and ft_memdel((void**)tmp) needs to be ft_memdel((void**) &tmp) in fnc ft_lstfreeone()

Comment: Tried that and it gets me this error : free(): invalid pointer. That's interesting though, because I would agree with you in theory (memdel receives **ap, frees *ap), and I don't really understand why it behaves that way. If somone is willing to give some insight about that, I'd gladly take them, I'm only one month into programming and still have a lot to learn...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems - you aren't actually deleting the nodes themselves because you didn't pass in the address of the pointer to the node.

The reason why ".:" is being deleted is because in `ft_lstfreeone` you need to `ft_memdel tmp->content` not `cursor->content`.

As coded you likely deleted ".:" when you deleted the node after it.

It's also likely why free() fails when you put the & in front of the tmp/cursor ft_memdel calls.

Comment: Ok, this got me a LOT closer ! Basically, I changed lstfreeone to receive **to_free instead of *to_free, changed every call to it accordingly, and also the cursor->content to tmp->content. I now get my little .: node back, but still have a free() invalid pointer error when freeing &tmp/cursor with memdel. I'll look into that tomorrow, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

As @TonyLee comments, `cursor` may point to a freed node, making following `cursor` a crap-shoot.  Why not save `cursor->next` before the `if` statement in the main code, and set `cursor` to it after  the `if`, so that the loop can progress safely whether or not the node gets freed, and avoid taking a chance?

Comment: Did that in both the function shown and the one displaying, which used the same kind of loop, but alas, nothing changed. Still a damn node missing and no idea why :/ Thanks anyway, I guess this little change will avoid some undefined behaviour.